# Manually trigger property change in ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a component with a property 'viewBox' that stores a POJO, with an observer on this property.  I want to be able to modify the properties of this viewBox without using set and then manually trigger a change on the viewBox.  Is this possible in ember.js ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the [notifyPropertyChange](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Observable.html#method_notifyPropertyChange) method on `Ember.Observable` to let Ember know a property has been changed through manual assignment.